# jQuery Increment buttons - not go below 0

Tags: jquery, button, increment

Just trying out a bit of dev with the button tag - quite new to me, as is the jQuery that is associated to it all.

I want to make the smallest value to be clicked 0. To not go into the minuses, basically.

Here is what I've got so far:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="1" size="3" maxlength="2"></input>

<button id="qtyplus" onclick="return false">+</button>
<button id="qtyminus" onclick="return false">-</button>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function(){
    $("#qtyplus").click(function(){
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    $("#qtyminus").click(function(){
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );

    });
  });

</script>
```

So, any idea what I have to add so that it doesn't go below 0?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to check the result of `Number(...)` to see if it's going to be less than zero. Have you tried anything on that front?

Answer (score 1):

Use an if case

```
   $("#qtyminus").click(function(){
      if($(':text[name="qty"]').val() !=0){
           $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );
      }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2aUgb/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#qtyminus").click(function(){
  if ($(":text[name='qty']").val() > 0)
  {
  $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );
  }
});
```

just like that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function(){
    $("#qtyplus").click(function(){     
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    $("#qtyminus").click(function(){
     if($('#qty').val()>1)
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );

    });
  });

</script>
```